# How can I duplicate the content of one table column into another column?

Tags: mysql

This is my table "data":

```
name  | descripton
======|===========
lara  | 
fred  |
todd  |
```

I want to transfer now the content of my column "name" into my column "description":

```
name  | descripton
======|===========
lara  | lara 
fred  | fred
todd  | todd
```

This is my approach:

```
update data
SET description=(select name from data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE `data` SET `description` = `name`
```

In this case the value of column `name` is set to column `description`. The value on column `description` is overwritten!

You can also add the value of column `name` to the end of the `description` (append):

```
UPDATE `data` SET `description` = ISNULL(`description`, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(`name`, '')

-- or using CONCAT_WS
UPDATE `data` SET `description` = TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', `description`, `name`))
```

Comment: If `description` has `null` values then using `+` is not a good idea.